# Is it possible to reference the same connection string in multiple places in a config file?

Tags: c#, xml, web-config, app-config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=test.com,1234;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>   
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="here reference the DefaultConnection connection string." />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Same connection strings needs to be referenced in multiple places. For typo mistakes I would like to be able to reference a single connection string in the same file.

Is this possible?

Comment: Move connection strings into a separate file and then use [Add as Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj714082(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: While the suggestion of @3615 seems to be impratical for Serilog, maybe using the [code configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#configuration) instead would be helpful? I.e. read from your normal connection string and then tell Serilog by code the connection string.

Comment: Thanks @UweKeim I missed that part. I can actually use 'DefaultConnection' directly for the value for SeriLog.

Comment: Oh in this case the table name is hard-coded.. Not exactly what I was looking for. It looks like there is no easy way to reference the same connection string in multiple places on the same config file...